# subtract from a range of rows in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Panda dataframe  with multiple columns. I would like to subtract a constant (100) from one of the columns ("order_id") if the "order_id" is greater than 100. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean indexing

```
df.loc[df['order_id'] > 100, 'order_id'] = df['order_id'] - 100
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest is use `-=` with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['order_id'] > 100, 'order_id'] -= 100
```

Another idea by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['order_id'] -= np.where(df['order_id'] > 100, 100, 0)
```

Or:

```
df['order_id'] -= (df['order_id'] > 100) * 100
```